# Covariance of $A$ and $B$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, covariance

If I know that $X$ and $Y$ are r.v that are positive and have non zero variance such that $X \perp Y$, how can I show that the random variables $W= X + Y$ and $Z = XY$
are positively correlated (i.e. $\operatorname{Cov}(W, Z) > 0$).

My solution:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(W, Z)&= E[WZ] - E[W]*E[Z]\\ &= E[XY] - E[X] * E[Y]\\
&= E[X]^2 - 2E[X]^2
\end{align}
vhich simplifies to
$\operatorname{Cov}(W,Z) =-E[X]^2$.

Is this correct or am I wrong? Please let me know and what the right approach is.

Comment: Your derivation looks wrong. A counter example should be $EY<0<EX$ and $EY<-{\rm Var}[Y]\,EX/{\rm Var}[X]\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. I'm not 100% sure what you mean, can you elaborate a little? thanks

Comment: You should reconsider your derivation. Not using mathJax isn't very helpful to attract better hints or answers.

Comment: @KurtG. I missed that, don't know why it didn't load correctly. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment. You should more carefully expand $W=X+Y\,:$

> \begin{align}{\rm Cov}(W,Z)&=\mathbb E[WZ]-\mathbb E[W]\,\mathbb E[Z]\\&=\mathbb E[X^2]\,\mathbb E[Y]+\mathbb E[X]\,\mathbb E[Y^2]-\mathbb E[X]^2\,\mathbb E[Y]-\mathbb E[X]\,\mathbb E[Y]^2\\&={\rm Var}[X]\,\mathbb E[Y]+{\rm Var}[Y]\,\mathbb E[X]\end{align}

Comment: Ok so since we know that they have non zero variance and X and Y are positive then the sum of $Var[][]+Var[][]$ is positive correct?

Comment: @andydandy That's true. I originally missed the condition that $\mathbb E[Y],\mathbb E[X]$ are positive.